# Numeric Scalebar round

Tags: qgis-3, scale-bar, round-function

The numeric scalebar in the map composer shows too detailed information on the output.
Moving the Map canvas changes the scale depending on the moved distance on the map.

We use EPSG 4258 (ETRS89)

How do I round the shown output by -2 digits? It should round to hundreds

Comment: Could you add a screenshot please? Because I haven't seen a scalebar with digits after the comma.

Comment: It doesn't show commas. But we are using large maps and want even numbers like 10000 instead of 9999 or 10001. Depending on the coordinate reference system it changes either with horizontal or vertical movement of the map layout

Comment: So, you're talking about the map composer?

Comment: yes............

Comment: And how does setting the map canvas scale to 1:10000 not suit your needs?

Comment: If I move the map canvas it starts to change. I guess that is because of the CRS. The further I go north the more the scale changes. We do serial printing. Changing the map canvas scale after every print is a thing we don't want to worry about.

Comment: Yeah, and that is some information that should have been there right from the start. Please edit your post accordingly. What CRS are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**For QGIS 3.*x*, in the layout** :

1. Draw a map item (Add item menu) and give an [item ID](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_items_options.html#item-common-properties)
2. Draw a [label item](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_label.html#the-label-item) and paste the following code :

   `[% '1/' || round(map_get(item_variables('my_map_item_ID'), 'map_scale')/100) || '00' %]`

**Explanation of the code** :

- || : concatenate two strings, here the '1/' part and the other calculed one, and finally the '00' for lasts units
- item_variables : access to variables of an item given its item ID, here 'my_map_item_ID'
- map_get : get item of map item given its attribute, here 'map_scale'
- /100 : to get hundreds
- round : to get rid of the decimal part for the denominator
- [% %] : enclose an expression in a label item