# Showing some feature in text label in Print Composer from Print Layout itself in QGIS 3.4.5

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, print-composer, expression

I was wondering if there is some expression that I can insert in a text label QGIS print layout that will allow me to print for example coordinates of the map inserted in the print layout itself.

Other features that I'd love to display automatically are:

- Before said converted coordinates in another CRS
- The scale of the map in print composer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Alexandre-Neto, he proposed to have map corner coordinates, here [the link](https://gisunchained.wordpress.com/2014/09/09/coordenadas-dos-cantos-do-mapa-em-qgis-map-corner-coordinates-in-qgis/) to his blog post.

With a little code, you can convert the coordinates in the CRS of your choice.

For the scale : [take a look here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/311231/93097).